# Объясните, пожалуйста, строку кода

Tags: python, numpy

Я взял из сети строку кода, который работает правильно, но я не знаю как

```
import numpy as np
randomArray = np.random.uniform(1, 100, size=(5,5))
columnSumm = list(map(sum,zip(*randomArray)))
print(randomArray, columnSumm)
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, третью строчку кода подробно, на простом языке.

Comment: https://docs-python.ru/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы создаете массив размером `5 на 5` с рандомными числами от 1 до 100, после создаете новый массив `1 на 5` из сумм каждого столбца.

`list` - создание списка

Функция `map()` используется для применения функции к каждому элементу итерируемого объекта (например, списка или словаря) и возврата нового итератора для получения результатов

`sum` - Суммирует элементы указанного объекта и возвращает результат.

функция `zip` позволяет пройтись одновременно по нескольким итерируемым объектам (спискам и др.)

Comment: В моём случае zip проходится по каждой строке массива?

Comment: да, в данном случае проходится по столбцам из-за заранее созданного списка.
пройдитесь принтом по каждому шагу и вы все поймете, начните с print(list(randomArray)) и тд

Comment: Cпасибо большое, понял, могу я ещё получить ответ, какие функции у символа * перед randomArray? Если символа нет, перед каждой строкой массива пишется array

Comment: передаёт все элементы списка. те spisok =['one','two'] print(*spisok) -> output : one two

Answer (score 3):

`zip(*my_list)` - это известный трюк в Vanilla Python для транспонирования матрицы (списка списков).

Пример:

```
In [56]: lst = [[1,2], [3,4]]

In [57]: list(zip(*lst))
Out[57]: [(1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

Но раз вы уже используете Numpy, то почему бы не воспользоваться его быстрыми и оптимизированными методами:

```
In [62]: randomArray.sum(axis=0)
Out[62]:
array([343.75311042, 216.14459965, 300.61339319, 128.05807225,
       223.37915629])

In [63]: columnSumm
Out[63]:
[343.7531104159996,
 216.14459964962612,
 300.6133931881401,
 128.05807225046016,
 223.3791562915357]
```

для больших массивов Numpy код будет работать на порядки быстрее